# Conexión remota a mysql local

Tags: mysql, xampp, puertos

Estoy queriendo hacer una conexión remota a mi máquina local, pero no logro conseguirlo.
He estado investigando en múltiples páginas de internet y aún no logro hacer que funcione.

Las cosas o pasos que he hecho son:

1. Configurar el port forwarding (redireccionamiento de puertos) en el router, coloco el puerto 3306 de entrada y la IP de la máquina donde está instalado el servicio mysql. He intentado con xampp cambiando la configuración del my.ini reemplazando local-bind:"127.0.0.1", por
   "0.0.0.0", para permitir conexiones desde cualquier IP. También intente con Mysql Server 8, en este caso usando el puerto 3307.
   2)Configure el firewall de windows agregando una "nueva regla de entrada", con ambos puertos (3306  y 3307)
2. Cree el usuario remoto en el servicio de mysql (xampp), con los siguientes comandos:
   create user "ejemplouser"@"%" identified by "password";
   grant all privileges on * . * to "ejemplouser"@"%";
   Algo raro que pasa es que cuando ingreso a la carpeta bin de mysql server 8, e ingreso via cmd con:
   mysql -u root -p, y hago un "show databases;" me muestra las bases de datos de xampp, no sé si eso influya en algo.
   Ya verifique que en services.msc  se estén ejecutando los servicios, y veo que solo el servicio  MySqlServer 8 (que yo creen en la instalación del mismo), se está ejecutando, pero el servicio de xampp no lo veo ahí.

Esas son básicamente las configuraciones que he hecho, espero alguien se pueda dar la oportunidad de leer mi caso y si puede auxiliarme en decirme qué estoy haciendo mal o qué es lo que me falta por configurar.
De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo o configuración de tu red, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).